# Sticky Navigation on Scroll > add class for page-content

Tags: html, jquery, css, onscroll

I'm using a script and would like to adjust it - but it does not work. So maybe someone can help me.
Script:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var sticky = navigation.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    navigation.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navigation.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

This script add the class sticky to navigation.
I would like to add the class "padding-page" to the class "page-content" in this function (also remove it) - as the sticky navigation is not relative anymore and the "page-content" jumps 48px more to top.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var sticky = navigation.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    navigation.classList.add("sticky padding-page");
  } else {
    navigation.classList.remove("sticky padding-page");
  }
}
```

Comment: But this version add the padding-page class to the navigation - but it should add it to the content-page class.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navigation = document.getElementById("navigation");
var welcome = document.getElementById("welcome");
var sticky = navigation.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    navigation.classList.add("sticky"); welcome.classList.add("padding-page");
  } else {
    navigation.classList.remove("sticky"); welcome.classList.remove("padding-page");
  }
}
```

Just created a id for the first content and add padding-page to this :) Works perfect